# EF Code First - navigation property without FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way in EF Code First to create navigation property between Blog and Post class without ending with FK in my DB? I can do it when I am using DB first thourgh the desginer but i couldnt figure out how to acheive that in code first.

Comment: a navigation property means: a property as a means for navigating through the object tree, either for EF or for you. If this navigation property requires the use of FK's, EF will create one for you. If you do not require the property for navigation through the object tree for query generation, you can ignore the property (.Ignore() or [NotMapped]). Otherwise you'll have to change the cardinality (many to many will leave all FK's in the mapping tables for example).

Comment: I want assosciation in my code to navigate thourgh the object tree for query generation but i dont want to add a FK to my scheme. i know that in DB first this is possible (i just add association in the designer without FK even exist and its works)

Comment: Associations don't work without the use of FK's. In one-to-zero..one relationships and one-to-many relationships, there must be an FK to identify the single target instance, in one-to-one relationships, the PK's of both tables act as FK's and in many-to-many relationships the FK's reside in the junction table. If you want to map a one-to-one relationship, read http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx , but notice in relationships are always FK's involved.